# Programmatic way to set Date & Time in Android

Tags: android

In the Android Setting > Date & Time, there is a check box next to "Automatic date and time, Use network-provided time".

I would like to turn this on programically.  I have tried things like `adb shell setprop persist.sys.timezone America/XXX` but I can't find the right property for the automatic date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

> adb shell date -s YYYYMMDD.HHmmss

Comment: This will set the time.  I was wondering if there was a way to programatically turn on "Automatic date and time"